# How to easily and securely share files on a linux system over the internet?

Tags: file-sharing, webdav

I can think of a couple of ways which are not that easy:

1. ftp - user needs ftp (or even ftps) client, active vs. passive, firewalls
2. https - only for download
3. webDAV - setup of apache is rather extensive
4. scp and normal user accounts - hard to secure the system from then local users

I guess I am searching for a simple webDAV server that is easy to setup and already contains sane defaults (and https support).

Should allow for upload-only directories (-wx permissions).

Comment: Consider this:
http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/75-debian/62-debian-webdav-share
Works now 3 yrs at our place.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, user-friendly solutions:

- [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) + [TrueCrypt](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/Truecrypt) (Dropbox exchanges binary diffs, so it has just a little transfer overhead).
- [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/)
- [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/)

As long as other solutions are concerned, you can setup what you prefer: nfs, ftp etc etc, and easily create encrypted tunnel with socat[1].

[1] ["SSL tunnel with mutual authentication, using socat"](http://www.wsec.be/blog/2011/02/10/ssl-tunnel-with-mutual-authentication-using-socat/)

Comment: Hm, dropbox and colleagues don't run on my linux system. They are remote services. Socat is not always sufficient when you have services that use multiple ports or dynamic ports from a port range (e.g. nfs. ftp ...) - and such a setup looks certainly more complicated/fragile than - say - configuring dovecot/postfix/nginx.

Comment: As you've wrote. Everything depends on user needs. I've mentioned above solutions, cause I believe in some cases might be helpful. If something more suitable to your needs will come to my mind, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can chroot ssh/scp sessions. Then, if you turn off password auth on the sshd you won't be able to be bruteforced.

What could be more secure, over the internet, than chrooted ssh via pubkeys?

Comment: Try being more helpful in your answer. If the person asks for easy solutions, a vague reference to chroot+ssh/scp (plus some keywords) will not help. This kind of answer might get you downvotes in the future.